# Symfony4 deploy to shared hosting getting error 500

Tags: php, symfony, cpanel, symfony4

I have deployed my symfony4 project to a shared hosting (infinityFree).
but when I go to my website I get a **500 Internal Server Error** :

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>   The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
>
> Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

My project works fine on local with dev mode.

In **htdocs/var/log/prod.depreciations.log** :

```
[2019-09-20 15:01:41] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder::root()" method called for the "liip_imagine" configuration is deprecated since Symfony 4.3 ... etc


[2019-09-20 15:01:41] php.INFO: User Deprecated: A tree builder without a root node is deprecated since Symfony 4.2 ... etc


[2019-09-20 15:01:41] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\ExtensionGuesser" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.3 ... etc

[2019-09-20 15:01:43] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The spaceless tag in "@LiipImagine/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig" at line 2 is deprecated since Twig 2.7, use the spaceless filter instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: The spaceless tag in \"@LiipImagine/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig\" at line 2 is deprecated since Twig 2.7 ... etc
```

There is no error log in htdocs/var/log/.
My project is deployed in htdocs, and in my htaccess as a sibling of the public folder I have :

```
php_value display_errors On
php_flag magic_quotes 1
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 1
php_value mbstring.http_input auto
php_value date.timezone Europe/Paris
DirectoryIndex public/index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
    #Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

In Cpanel php version is 7.3 (default) and I don't have ssh access with infinityfree. Ive followed this tutorial
 https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html

Comment: Do you have logs with "CRITICAL" level?

Comment: In htdocs/var I have cache (dev + log folder) and log directory (dev.log with 0B and prod.depreciations.log)

Comment: dev.log is weird, did you configure APP_ENV or SYMFONY_ENV to use prod environment?

Comment: Ive generated .env.local.php with composer dump-env prod                         <?php
return array (
  'APP_ENV' => 'prod',

Comment: I'm still getting error 500 even if I edit the .env file APP_ENV=prod

Comment: Try to set APP_DEBUG=true on your prod server and check results

Comment: Ive added   APP_DEBUG=true  to .env  and no critical error in  log directory

Comment: ok and now when you load your app in production you should see the profiler and debug messages, isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by profiler ?  development tool that gives detailed information about the execution of any request ?  Ive reupladed the project with the edited .env file and nothing has changed

Comment: Did you see errors pages like this the first one here https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html ?

Comment: No I'm getting this :                                                                                                    
Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".

Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
(ps: Je suis français c'est pour mon stage de fin d'étude j'aimerais mettre mon site sur mon cv je peux t'envoyer le zip de mon mini projet et les logs de mon webhost par mail ???)

Comment: Yes you can but if the logs are the same that on your question I can't do anything more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem was my database password  in .env.local.php (or .env)         make sure you give the **cpanel password**.
ps: to generate .env.local.php  before deploying run in your local project :

```
composer dump-env prod
```

You will have .env.local.php :

```
 return array (
  'APP_ENV' => 'prod',
  'APP_SECRET' => ' ',
  'DATABASE_URL' => 'mysql://your_username:your_password@your_host/the_db_name',
  'MAILER_URL' => 'null://localhost',
);
```

Hope this help